# Creating scatterplot per df column in Pandas/Python, when number of columns is unknown

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scatter-plot

I am new to Python and Stackoverflow. I am trying to create a combined/merged plot of scatterplots for a pd.dataframe per column.

My data looks like this;

[image: Image of Data]

I would like to create a combined scatterplot where the first x-value is Assignment 1 (string/header) and the correponding y-values  are the values found in column 'Assignment1'. I want to do this for each assignment and combine the scatterplots in one plot.

The problem revolves around the fact that I don't know how many columns I will have to deal with so I have to create a general code that takes this into account. I do however know that the first two columns consist of Ids and Names i.e ([2:]) I added the header for the dataframe manually to give you an example of the data, so I would also like to ask how one names headers when one doesn't know the total amount of columns..?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Python 3.6.1 64bits, Qt 5.6.2, PyQt5 5.6 on Darwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

Want you want to do is iterate over your data to and append your data points to lists which you can then plot.

```
def plotXY(gradeMatrix):
#First two empty lists are defined
pointsx = []
pointsy = []

#The grades of the Matrix, of the valid data, is now made in to 
#x and y coordinates, with a random small number added. 
for grades in gradeMatrix:
    for g in range(len(grades)):

        #(note :I added small random values  to differentiate the data 
        # points for viewing) 

        # append values found via the loop in the data to your created lists 
        # for x and y
        pointsx.append(g + random()*0.2 - 0.1)
        pointsy.append(float(grades[g]) + random()*0.2 - 0.1)

#The possible grades going op the y-axis are stored in a list
gradesy = [12,10,7,4,2,0,-3]

# Create data ticks, x values and y values for the plot.
plt.yticks(gradesy, [str(x) for x in gradesy])
plt.xticks(np.arange(10),np.arange(10))

# set range for the Y axis
plt.ylim(-4,13)

# create bar plot
plt.plot(pointsx,pointsy,'bs')

# Legend - labels 
plt.title("Occurance of grades given for different assignments")    
plt.ylabel("Grade")
plt.xlabel("Assignement number")


# show plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you for taking the time to help ! :)

Comment: No problem, happy coding!